# PHP mail delivers attachment or message, but not both

Tags: php

The PHP below will attach the file from the server, but will not allow me to edit the message input for the body of the email.

```
<?php
  $fileatt = './dwrdocuments/dwr.fdf'; // Path to the file
  $fileatt_type = "application/octet-sdiveam"; // File Type
  $fileatt_name = date(mdy_his).'_dwr.fdf'; 
  $email_from = $_POST['From']; // Who the email is from
  $email_subject = 'DWR Submittal'; // The Subject of the email
  $email_txt = $_POST['Comments']; // Message that the email has in it

  $email_to = 'admin@example.com'; // Who the email is to

  $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

  $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
  fclose($file);

  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-divansfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $email_message . "\n\n";

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

  $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
  $data . "\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

  $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  header ("Location: ../confirm.html");  
?>
```

If I do input a message for the body of the email by replacing:

```
  $email_message . "\n\n";
```

the attachment does not come through, but the message will... along with some gibberish

```
--==Multipart_Boundary_xd05fe3fbc7afe814087a952a9c31f1fax Content-Type: application/octet-sdiveam; name="061711_080900_dwr.fdf" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 JUZERi0xLjIKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQoxIDAgb2JqCjw8IAovRkRGIDw8IC9GaWVsZHMgWyA8PC9U KFdvcmtfRGF0ZSkvVihramgpPj48PC9UKE1haW50ZW5hbmNlX0FyZWEpL1YoKT4+PDwvVChSb3V0 ZV9OdW1iZXIpL1YoKT4+PDwvVChEdWVfRGF0ZSkvVigyMDExLTA2LTE2IDIyOjI2OjAxKT4+PDwv VChSb2FkX1NlZ21lbnRfSUQpL1YoKT4+PDwvVChDcm9zc19TZWN0aW9uX1Bvc2l0aW9uKS9WKCk+ Pjw8L1QoTG9jYWxfTmFtZSkvVigpPj48PC9UKEZhY2lsaXR5X05hbWUpL1YoKT4+PDwvVChGYWNp bGl0eV9BZGRyZXNzKS9WKCk+Pl0gCi9GIChodHRwOi8vY2FnZWRuYXRpb24uY29tL2pjcy9waHAv ZHdyX2Zvcm0ucGRmKSAvSUQgWyA8ZjIxODgyZTJmOGQxOGJjYjY5OGRhYzlmNTllNzIwYWM+Cl0g Pj4gCj4+IAplbmRvYmoKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAovUm9vdCAxIDAgUiAKCj4+CiUlRU9GCg==
```

I would like to include a body to the email for comments and notes.

Comment: Have you got the \n\n after your custom message? (You could just initialize $email_message to your custom message)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a mailer library? There are a lot out there, like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). You'd save yourself the headache of dealing with the email details.

Comment: I have tried them before, and my attachment would always 0kb out. Swiftmailer wouldn't 0kb the attachment, but it would allways come up corrupt.

Comment: I've been using swift for a while, with no problems. You sure php had read access to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ending headers with \r\n?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php